# How to delete Sidekiq Enterprise periodic jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Sidekiq Enterprise includes support for [Periodic Jobs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Periodic-Jobs) and includes an example of using the initializer to register jobs:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.periodic do |mgr|
    # see any crontab reference for the first argument
    # e.g. http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference
    mgr.register('0 * * * *', SomeHourlyWorkerClass)
    mgr.register('* * * * *', SomeWorkerClass, retry: 2, queue: 'foo')
    mgr.register(cron_expression, worker_class, job_options={})
  end
end
```

After registering a job, how does one delete/unregister a job? For example, if the worker is no longer used and should not run anymore how do you safely remove the registered job from Redis? Removing it from the initializer and restarting Sidekiq doesn't do it, and the API doesn't appear to offer deletion, instead saying *The Periodic API allows you to list registered periodic jobs and see enqueue history*.

There is an API for deleting jobs in a regular queue:

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new("mailer")
queue.each do |job|
  job.klass # => 'MyWorker'
  job.args # => [1, 2, 3]
  job.delete if job.jid == 'abcdef1234567890'
end
```

But attempting to adapt this for the periodic jobs API:

```
Sidekiq::Periodic::LoopSet.new.each do |lop|
  lop.delete
end
```

...raises an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for #<Sidekiq::Periodic::Loop:0x007fff0a48dbe8>
```

The Redis db shows that Sidekiq has created a `loop-uniqueid` key for each loop, as well as a `loop-history-uniqueid` key and `loops-uniqueid` key. Should I destroy all of these keys? Is it best to destroy all these keys and then re-register all current jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sidekiq Enterprise leader role was held by a secondary server. When the leader role is held the Periodic Jobs are locked and cannot be modified. Shut down all Sidekiq servers, including the leader, and then restart Sidekiq to purge and re-register all jobs from the initializer.

There is no need to use the API to delete Periodic Jobs.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: The "Ent Periodic Jobs" page should ideally be updated to document this locking behavior by the "leader".

Answer (score -1):

Just run this:

```
Sidekiq::Cron::Job.destroy_all!
```

As described in [sidekiq-cron docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sidekiq-cron/0.3.0)

Comment: Well, when I posted about this three and a half years ago I wasn't using sidekiq-cron. I was using Sidekiq Enterprise, as detailed in the question title and the post itself.

Comment: Oh, actually we also use Sidekiq Enterprise, and I gave this command to our DevOps and they reported that they installed the gem, ran the command and it fixed the issue. Though yeah, probably it's not the best solution.