# Deleting a periodic job in sidekiq

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I am trying to delete a Sidekiq Enterprise periodic job for an app, and I'm not sure how one goes about deleting the periodic job itself after deleting the schedule from the initialize and deleting the worker job.

I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876565/how-to-delete-sidekiq-enterprise-periodic-jobs) from earlier but the app in question has other jobs (both periodic and regular sidekiq jobs) and I cannot just globally blow away all scheduled periodic jobs and would prefer to not have to totally shut down and restart sidekiq either. Is there a way I can just get the specific job I am deleting out of redis so that it will no longer try to run at the next scheduled time?

Comment: Have you tried using the sidekiq web interface directly ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to deploy your code change and restart Sidekiq for it to pick up periodic changes.